# Extract test coverage from the docker container in GitLab-CI

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab-CI and running the java application that is built with help of Gradle.

There is an application running inside the Docker container. In parallel, the job **automation** runs the ApiTestSuite test suite along with the java application.

*The question is:* How can I get the test coverage from the running application after the **ApiTestSuite** suite ends?

Here is the simplified version of the GitLab job:

```
automation:
  stage: validate
  tags:
    - dind
  variables:
    PROFILE: some-profile
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
    - redis:5-alpine
    - webcenter/activemq
  before_script:
    - docker run --detach --name MY_APPLICATION
  script:
    - ./gradlew ApiTestSuite
```

I can fetch the code coverage while running unit test cases but have some problems understanding how it can be implemented for the example above.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can map test results folder inside `MY_APPLICATION` container to external folder using `run -v external:internal` and then tell Gitlab CI to use this folder https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsreports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tell java to use JaCoCo Agent while running the application inside the container

`-javaagent:/home/java/jacoco.jar=destfile=folder_inside_contrainer/jacoco-it.exec,append=true`

2. Configure Agent to write the results into **folder_inside_contrainer**

`replace *folder_inside_contrainer* with the one you will share with the host later on`

3. Share folder **folder_inside_contrainer** between the container and the host (in this case GitLab Job)

`docker run -d -v gitlab_folder:folder_inside_contrainer`

4. Export results that are in .exec format into .html format via JaCoCo-cli.jar

`java -jar jacococli.jar report gitlab_folder/jacoco-it.exec --classfiles path_to_app_compiled_classes --html coverage/api-coverage-html`

5. Grab the coverage from HTML and display it for that job

```
api-coverage:
  stage: release
  script:
    - 'apt-get install -y unzip'
    - 'curl -L "https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jacoco/jacoco/0.8.6/jacoco-0.8.6.zip" -o jacoco.zip'
    - 'unzip jacoco'
    - 'java -jar lib/jacococli.jar report gitlab_folder/jacoco-it.exec --classfiles path_to_app_compiled_classes --html coverage/api-coverage-html'
    - grep -oP "Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%" coverage/api-coverage-html/index.html
  coverage: "/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%/"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
```

Comment: Can. you please share any gradle example if you have for the above steps